# Why is serializing Integer produce too much overhead?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm investigating serialization in Java and wrote the very simple code:

```
public class OutputStreamStub extends OutputStream{
    public List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        a.add(b);
    }
}

OutputStreamStub stub = new OutputStreamStub();
ous = new ObjectOutputStream(stub); //stub.a contains 4 bytes now
ous.writeObject(new Integer(12342134));   //stub.a contains 81 bytes now
```

After the 4 bytes integer we got 81 bytes. Why do we have too much overhead? And why do we have 4 bytes written after creating the `ObjectOutputStream`?

Comment: @Michael I want to understand which bytes are being written down to a stream when I call `ObjectOutputStream::writeObject` with an `Integer` argument.

Comment: I thought `Integer` is serialized like any object. Without unboxing.

Comment: Wait a second. Your code doesn't even compile. Where is `ous` defined?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html) is a description of what's written to an `ObjectOutputStream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have **JDK8** so when i look at the source of the constructor:

```
public ObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    verifySubclass();
    bout = new BlockDataOutputStream(out);
    handles = new HandleTable(10, (float) 3.00);
    subs = new ReplaceTable(10, (float) 3.00);
    enableOverride = false;
    writeStreamHeader();
    bout.setBlockDataMode(true);
    if (extendedDebugInfo) {
        debugInfoStack = new DebugTraceInfoStack();
    } else {
        debugInfoStack = null;
    }
}
```

You can see that after some verifying and initializing `writeStreamHeader()` is invoked. It's implementation looks like this:

```
protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
    bout.writeShort(STREAM_MAGIC);   // STREAM_MAGIC = 0xaced
    bout.writeShort(STREAM_VERSION); // STREAM_VERSION = 5
}
```

Which just appends the header information. So I am guessing that's where the extra 4 bytes come from.

Comment: Thanks. Understood. But what about serialiIng `Integer` object? Why too excessive?

Comment: Java SE is an object-oriented library.  The source code is not a good source of information, because it is an implementation detail which may change in future releases.  The Java serialization specification, on the other hand (which is linked to in a comment above), is permanent and public, which makes it a reliable and stable source of information.